# Autowiring of KafkaTemplate is not working in

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a code from someone else which basically processes an input and sends a message to Kafka. I have to write an integration test for this, and am having issues with autowiring. Below is the code, and the error I get is:

```bash
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(String, Object)" because "this.kafkaTemplate" is null
```

I have tried all suggestions here on Stackoverflow, such as adding notations `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class), @SpringBootTest(classes=...)` and so on, but not managed to find a solution. I suspect I am missing something fundamental about dependency-injection.

```java
@Service
class ProcessService {
  private final MsgProducer msgProducer;

  public ProcessService (MsgProducer msgProducer) {
    this.msgProducer = msgProducer;
  }

  public void sendMsg(String message) {
    // Processing of data
    msgProducer.sendMessage(message);
  }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class MsgProducer implements ProducerService {
  @Value("${app.kafka.topic}")
  private String topic;

  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

  @Override
  public void sendMessage(String message) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
  }
}

public interface ProducerService {
  void sendMessage(String message);
}

@EnableKafka
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class Configuration {
  @Value(value="${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
  private String bootstrap;

  @Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrap);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new Kafkatemplate<>(this.producerFactory());
  }
```

```java
class ProcessServiceIT {
  private MsgProducer producer = new MsgProducer();

  @Test
  void testProducer() {
    producer.send()
  }
}
```